# Issue on yum update with kernel

Tags: linux, yum, kernel, openvz, update

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package e2fsprogs-resize2fs-static.x86_64 0:1.42.3-3.el6.1.ovz will be installed
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:2.6.32-358.2.1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6 for package: kernel-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64
Package kernel-firmware-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.noarch is obsoleted by vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab075.2.noarch which is already installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kernel-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: kernel-firmware >= 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6
           Removing: vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab075.2.noarch (@openvz-kernel-rhel6)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6
           Updated By: vzkernel-firmware-2.6.32-042stab076.5.noarch (openvz-kernel-rhel6)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-358.el6.noarch (base)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-358.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-358.0.1.el6
           Available: kernel-firmware-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.noarch (updates)
               kernel-firmware = 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
kernel-2.6.32-358.0.1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of kernel-firmware >= ('0', '2.6.32', '358.0.1.el6')
[root@HOST ~]# uname -a
Linux HOST.DOMAIN.SITE 2.6.32-042stab075.2 #1 SMP Tue Mar 5 15:21:53 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is this issue because it is trying to install 2 kernels?

How do I fix this so a yum update works?

Answer (score 1):

The default CentOS 6.4 kernel can't be installed because the OpenVZ kernel is blocking it. This is expected, since you probably don't *want* the OpenVZ kernel to be replaced with the CentOS kernel.

If you have other packages to update, use `--skip-broken` as it suggested.

This issue will be resolved when OpenVZ updates its kernel packages.

Comment: Well it is an OpenVZ node box, so I would want the openvz kernel installed and updated over the default centos kernel.

Comment: That's what I said!

Answer (score 0):

As on the openvz vzkernel-firmware page[1](http://wiki.openvz.org/Vzkernel-firmware) explains, the package `vzkernel-firmware` must be excluded in the yum repo file to avoid conflicts on Centos installations.